# different output is generated every time I run the code

Tags: c, scanf

Here in this code, when I execute it, it sometimes display correct value of nT and nF, sometimes it display correct nF but incorrect nT(i.e 0).
Why is it so??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned char nT,nF;    
    puts("Enter No. of Testcases & Faults");
    scanf(" %hhu %hhu",&nT,&nF);
    printf("\n %hhu %hhu",nT,nF);
}
```

Comment: Sadly you've ruined this question with that screenshot. Please type the output.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has changed such that the answers are partially no longer relevant

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `%hhu` as the format specifier for an `unsigned char`. (Obscure I know: one for the pub quiz.) Also, you might want to introduce some spaces between your formatters:

```
int read = scanf("%hhu %hhu %s", &nT, &nF, extension);
```

Currently the behaviour of your program is *undefined*.

Prior to C99 you're pretty much at the mercy of your compiler.

---

Further notes:

1. Always check the return value of `scanf` which gives you useful information about the number of inputs that are read successfully.
2. `extension` is only good for 4 characters plus the nul-terminator.

Comment: it is still displaying output as '0 3' if I entered '2 3 hello' as input

Comment: There ain't enough room for "Hello". Don't forget it contains a nul-terminator.

Comment: So what? There still ain't room. The literal `"Hello"` requires 6 bytes, not 5.

Comment: I removed extension from scanf but the problem still persists

Comment: Did you check the return value of `scanf`? And consider introducing some spaces between the formatters - which I've now added to the answer.

Comment: the return value of scanf is 2

Comment: @MiniAgarwal: Please get a good C book and work through the chapters. You ask about very basic stuff.

Comment: but I still did not get the answer

Comment: @MiniAgarwal: Did you change the conversion specifiers for `nT` and `nF` to `%hhu` as shown above?